# Hitomis circle menu how to open new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using [Hitomis circle menu library](https://github.com/Hitomis/CircleMenu) but don't know how I can open a specific activity on clicking a specific submenu?

I think there is no feature like this in Hitomis library but let me know if there is any way to do it.

> here is the java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CircleMenu circleMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    circleMenu = (CircleMenu) findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);
    circleMenu.setMainMenu(Color.parseColor("#CDCDCD"), R.mipmap.menuop, R.mipmap.menucl)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#258CFF"), R.drawable.chrome)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#30A400"), R.drawable.drive)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF4B32"), R.drawable.googlesearch)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#8A39FF"), R.drawablegmail)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.drawable.youtube)
            .setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMenuSelected(int index) {}

            }).setOnMenuStatusChangeListener(new OnMenuStatusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMenuOpened() { }

                @Override
                public void onMenuClosed() {}

            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Menu selected listener returns the index of the menu which is clicked for ex
if you click on the first sub menu item which is `addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#258CFF"), R.drawable.chrome)`
it returns index= 0, 
now if you want to open activity on specific sub menu click you can do this like below

```
setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMenuSelected(int index) {
       switch(index){
    case 0: startActivity(new Intent(this,FirstActivity.class));break;
    case 1: startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));break;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `if`:

```java
.setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMenuSelected(int i) {
        if (i==0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (i==1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```